# Rails app, and need to add tags to a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, tags

I have this quiz rails app linked to an IRC bot who asks questions (yes, on IRC), where I have this `Question` model which contains, well, questions, answers, hints, and a few more things.

I started with `Quiz` model (like, say, the special Halloween or Christmas quiz)  with a `quiz_id` in the `questions` table, then, I told myself, that it would be nice to be able to categorize the questions, so I added a `Category` model (like, say, Movies or Books), with a `category_id` in the `questions`.

Now, my users would like to be able to add a question to one or more quiz, and to assign one or more categories to questions…

So, I've been thinking about removing the `Quiz` and `Category` models and replace them with tags, so that, there will be a halloween tag, a movie tag, and a question can have "halloween movie christmas" for tags.

In my searchs, I've seen quite a few ways to include tags like `acts_as_taggable`, `acts_as_taggable_on_steroids` or whatever else someone has imagined :-)

Now, I'm wondering what I should do, and so, I'm asking, what you have done, how you've done it, why you did it this way.

Comment: you got one massive unibrow my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

acts_as_taggable_on_steroids is older, but it still works, and is still being maintained. Be sure you're visiting the primary repository for it:

http://svn.viney.net.nz/things/rails/plugins/acts_as_taggable_on_steroids/

You can use acts_as_taggable_on_steroids with named_scopes, here's an article that shows how:

[Speed Up and named_scope acts_as_taggable_on_steroids Finds](http://codeintensity.blogspot.com/2008/11/speed-up-and-namedscope.html)

The actual addition to your model is pretty trivial (this is directly from the article above):

```
named_scope :tagged_with, lambda { |tags| YourModel.find_options_for_find_tagged_with(tags) }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think Category can easily be replaced by tags, because they are both used to add metadata to a question.

However, I have my doubts about the Quiz model. If you only use the Quiz model to group your questions, it could be possible to replace it with tags. But I think the Quiz model will include more functionality than just grouping alone. For example, score keeping, picking the next question, etc. So I would keep the Quic model intact.

To implement tagging, acts_as_taggable_on_steroids does work, but is a bit old. It would be nice to have a tagging plugin that uses named_scope in the background, as it would make the plugin far more flexible.